# How to avoid manually deleting the content of an EditTextPreference when the user want to change its content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have the following preference screen on my API 29 app :

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/sample_header">

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="sample_id"
            app:title="@string/sample_id_title"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The EditTextPreference is set to numeric input :

```
public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
}
```

When the user opens the sample_id preference, the text is set to the old numeric value, as expected, and the cursor is placed at the beginning of the text. It's important for the application that the current value is shown to the user.

To change that value, the user has to first scroll to the end of the text or select it, delete the old content, and then enter the new numeric text.

I would like to have the following behavior: The old text get deleted when the user types in a new text.

One implementation would be to have the text content already selected. Therefore it would be replaced as soon as the user types in a new text.

I haven't found a way to force the selection of the text on edit.

Another sub-optimal solution would be to have the cursor placed at the end of the text on edit. Just pressing a couple of backspace is more convenient than having to fist move to cursor to the end or to select the old text content.

My question is :
How to avoid the need to first delete the old content to enter a new one ?

Comment: You can do all you want with a '<Preference> i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can overide the focus so when that editText is focus'd it can either clear the text or change the value to hint.

```
setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus & v instanceof EditText){
                        ((EditText) v).setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Set to hint

```
.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus & v instanceof EditText){
                String value = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
                    ((EditText) v).setText("");
                    ((EditText) v).setHint(value);
            }
        }
    });
```